# Различия Yandex.Tank и JMeter?

Tags: яндекс-танк, jmeter

Какие задачи могут решить эти инструменты как по отдельности, так и вместе? В чем плюсы и минусы каждого из них? кроме платформы, которую они используют... Никак не могу понять... гугл не помог.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Если коротко, Yandex Tank - это враппер над несколькими утилитами нагрузочного тестирования (включая JMeter) предоставляющий унифицированный интерфейс для их конфигурации, запуска и построения отчетов вне зависимости от того, какая утилита используется "под капотом".

[image: Yandex Tank Arthitecture]

Среди дополнительных "фишек", которые предоставляет Yandex Tank по сравнению с JMeter "из коробки"

- **Monitoring Plugin** - слежение за основными метриками тестируемого приложения (процессор, память, своп, итд)
- **Auto-stop** - возможность остановить тест на основе разных критериев (если время отклика превышает заданное значение, если количество ошибок за единицу времени выше чем х, и т.д)
- **Console on-line screen** - отображение в консоли в реальном времени основных статистических данных
- **Resource Check** - проверка свободной памяти/места на диске
- и т.д.

Остальные модули с подробным описанием найдете в [документации Yandex Tank](https://yandextank.readthedocs.org/en/latest/).

Если по каким-то причинам вам не хватает фунцкионала JMeter (даже [включая плагины](https://jmeter-plugins.org/)), можно еще глянуть на [Taurus](http://gettaurus.org/), принцип тот же, что и в Yandex Tank, но побольше фич и более адекватный формат конфигурационных файлов.

Answer (score 4):

Нельзя сравнивать JMeter с Yandex Tank. 
Yandex.Tank яляеться системой менеджмента тестов, и он может работать с тем же JMeter. 
Так же к нему можно подключить и другие генераторы нагрузки:

- Phantom
- BGF
- Pandora
- и все тот же JMeter

все зависит от стощей перед Вами задачей